# Does Chromium networking implement TCP stack

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, chromium

I started to look at the Chrome networking stack and found it is extremely intriguing. Its documentation is pretty high level and a bit out-of-dated, thus a bit confused. A couple newbie questions:

1) Is TCP stack implemented in Chromium networking stack?
I saw TCPSocket implementations there, does that mean Chromium networking implements the whole TCP stack?

2) What else does TCP include besides TCP socket implementation (and related algorithms)?

3) Is Chromium operating a user space TCP stack?

Comment: Can't you just continue reading the code and answer this question yourself?

Comment: [tag:chromium] is a Web browser. It almost certainly relies on TCP support in the operating system. Too broad.